# Bathroom Exhaust Fan venting

Tags: bathroom, fans, exhaust

I need to install a exhaust fan for a bathroom in Dallas Texas on the first floor. The home is two story home. There are two optionsto exhaust the air out. One is exhaust the air out on the side of the home through a brick wall. The other choice is to exhaust the air by cutting into the drywall and fireblocks all the way up into the attic and to the roof.

Which choice is better for long term for making sure there are major problems in the future. Cutting into the brick for a side wall air venting or out the roof?

I understand that a core drilling is used to cut into the brick and everything between the outside to get to the inside but I am not sure if this would cause any long term maintenance issues for cutting into bricks versus the roof access.

Comment: This is partly a  matter of opinion, and partly a matter of other factors which we don't know about. For example, what's outside the wall? What's the roof made of? I suggest that you have someone local look at it if you can't decide yourself. From what I know I'd probably go out the wall.

Comment: Im with Isherwood, take the shorter run out the wall.  But there are many things to consider for your specific conditions and cost.

Comment: Hello thank you for the information reply. What are somethings i would need to consider?